# Change font size in Primefaces 5.2 <p:chart jqplot-xaxis-tick

Tags: charts, primefaces, jqplot

How to change font size in p:chart bar jqplot-xaxis-tick? I use Primefaces 5.2 and overwrite style class not working.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to JQPlot you can change the Font Size and Font Family: http://www.jqplot.com/examples/rotated-tick-labels.php

So in PF you can use the Chart Extender feature and do this...

**JAVA:**

```
final LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();
model.setExtender("chartExtender");
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function chartExtender() {
    this.cfg.axesDefaults = {
    tickOptions: {
      fontFamily: 'Georgia',
      fontSize: '10pt',
      angle: -30
    }
   };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Where paste Javascript code? In external file? How to include to managedbean?

Comment: Javascript goes in your XHTML page where you p:chart is being used.